# Running Counter Based On Date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with alert history, containing a start date, end_date and reason for the alert.

I want for every date of the last 30 days to compute total alerts that happened that day, this means if an alert started day 1 and is still ongoing (end date is null) then it will count for all the days from day 1 to last.

This the query that I have come up with

```
select cal.trunc_date,assets.group_id,
       alert.*,
       count( alert.asset_id)
             over (PARTITION BY alert.REASON_ID ORDER BY 
                 cal.trunc_date) TOTAL_ASSETS
from g_alert_history alert,
  v_app_calendar cal,V_ACTIVE_ASSETS assets
where REASON_ID in (1,2)
  and assets.asset_id=alert.asset_id
  and assets.group_id=1462
  and cal.trunc_date >= trunc(systimestamp - 30)
  and alert.START_DATE_DEVICE >= trunc(systimestamp - 30)
  and alert.START_DATE_DEVICE >= cal.trunc_date
  and alert.START_DATE_DEVICE  <= cal.trunc_date +1
  and nvl (alert.END_DATE_DEVICE, systimestamp)
  >=cal.trunc_date;
```

View `v_app_calendar` contains dates and `V_ACTIVE_ASSETS` contains the `group_id` that I want to check.

The problem is that i get duplicates, triplicates etc.

Here is the result:

```
TRUNC_DATE  GROUP_ID  REASON_ID  ASSET_ID  GEOFENCE_ID  START_DATE_DEVICE                END_DATE_DEVICE                  TOTAL_ASSETS
---------   --------  ---------  --------  -----------  -------------------------------  -------------------------------  ------------
03-FEB-19       1462          1      1704          134  03-FEB-19 11.50.09.385000000 AM                                             13
03-FEB-19       1462          1      1704          134  03-FEB-19 11.55.09.475000000 AM                                             13
03-FEB-19       1462          1      1704          134  03-FEB-19 12.00.10.073000000 PM                                             13
03-FEB-19       1462          1      1704          134  03-FEB-19 12.05.11.126000000 PM                                             13
03-FEB-19       1462          1      1704          134  03-FEB-19 12.10.12.668000000 PM                                             13
03-FEB-19       1462          1      1704          134  03-FEB-19 12.15.12.858000000 PM                                             13
03-FEB-19       1462          1      1704          134  03-FEB-19 11.45.09.283000000 AM                                             13
03-FEB-19       1462          1      1704          134  03-FEB-19 11.20.03.587000000 AM                                             13
03-FEB-19       1462          1      1704          134  03-FEB-19 11.25.05.434000000 AM                                             13
03-FEB-19       1462          1      1704          134  03-FEB-19 11.30.07.294000000 AM                                             13
03-FEB-19       1462          1      1704          134  03-FEB-19 11.35.09.141000000 AM                                             13
03-FEB-19       1462          1      1704          134  03-FEB-19 11.40.09.251000000 AM                                             13
03-FEB-19       1462          1      1704          134  03-FEB-19 12.20.14.178000000 PM                                             13
05-FEB-19       1462          1      1663          134  05-FEB-19 02.33.02.475000000 PM                                             14
09-FEB-19       1462          1      1663          134  09-FEB-19 09.33.02.475000000 PM  09-FEB-19 11.33.22.475000000 PM            16
09-FEB-19       1462          1      1782          149  09-FEB-19 02.33.02.475000000 PM  09-FEB-19 02.36.02.475000000 PM            16
11-FEB-19       1462          1      2647          134  11-FEB-19 09.56.08.325000000 AM                                            140
11-FEB-19       1462          1      2647          164  11-FEB-19 09.56.08.325000000 AM                                            140
11-FEB-19       1462          1      2646          164  11-FEB-19 10.03.31.611000000 AM                                            140
11-FEB-19       1462          1      2646          134  11-FEB-19 10.03.31.611000000 AM                                            140
11-FEB-19       1462          1      1781          164  11-FEB-19 10.14.09.612000000 AM                                            140
11-FEB-19       1462          1      2647          134  11-FEB-19 11.55.20.281000000 AM                                            140
11-FEB-19       1462          1      1781          134  11-FEB-19 10.14.09.612000000 AM                                            140
11-FEB-19       1462          1      2647          164  11-FEB-19 10.55.32.300000000 AM                                            140
11-FEB-19       1462          1      1781          134  11-FEB-19 02.52.45.104000000 PM                                            140
11-FEB-19       1462          1      1781          164  11-FEB-19 03.20.40.461000000 PM                                            140
11-FEB-19       1462          1      1781          134  11-FEB-19 03.20.40.461000000 PM                                            140
11-FEB-19       1462          1      1781          164  11-FEB-19 08.28.13.331000000 PM                                            140
11-FEB-19       1462          1      1781          134  11-FEB-19 08.28.13.331000000 PM                                            140
11-FEB-19       1462          1      1781          134  11-FEB-19 03.20.42.461000000 PM                                            140
11-FEB-19       1462          1      1781          134  11-FEB-19 08.28.25.939000000 PM                                            140
11-FEB-19       1462          1      1781          164  11-FEB-19 08.28.25.939000000 PM                                            140
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need data at day level, then you have to apply distinct clause after converting timestamp columns to date.

some thing like below -

```
select cal.trunc_date,assets.group_id,
       alert.req_col,
       cast(alert.start_date_device as date),
       cast(alert.end_date_device as date)
       count( alert.asset_id)
             over (PARTITION BY alert.REASON_ID ORDER BY 
                 cal.trunc_date) TOTAL_ASSETS
from g_alert_history alert,
  v_app_calendar cal,V_ACTIVE_ASSETS assets
where REASON_ID in (1,2)
  and assets.asset_id=alert.asset_id
  and assets.group_id=1462
  and cal.trunc_date >= trunc(systimestamp - 30)
  and alert.START_DATE_DEVICE >= trunc(systimestamp - 30)
  and alert.START_DATE_DEVICE >= cal.trunc_date
  and alert.START_DATE_DEVICE  <= cal.trunc_date +1
  and nvl (alert.END_DATE_DEVICE, systimestamp)
  >=cal.trunc_date;
```

Data which you have provided is not duplicate as it containse unique timestamp for each records.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

Dates table contains all dates for the last 30 days, including today.

I also changed your `JOIN` syntax to a newer form.

```
with dates as (
    select trunc(sysdate) - (level - 1) trunc_date from dual connect by level<=30
)
select dates.trunc_date
     , count(alert.asset_id)
  from g_alert_history alert
  join v_app_calendar cal
    on (alert.START_DATE_DEVICE between cal.trunc_date and (cal.trunc_date +1)
        and nvl (alert.END_DATE_DEVICE, systimestamp) >= cal.trunc_date )
  join V_ACTIVE_ASSETS assets
    on (assets.asset_id=alert.asset_id)
 where REASON_ID in (1,2)
   and dates.trunc_date between trunc(alert.START_DATE_DEVICE) and nvl(alert.END_DATE_DEVICE, trunc(sysdate))
   and cal.trunc_date >= trunc(systimestamp - 30)
   and assets.group_id=1462
 group by dates.trunc_date
```

I hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a daily count of all alarms occurring on that day (the alarm could have started on a previous day and or ended on a future day), then you want to use an aggregate count grouped by day (and possibly other criteria) and not an analytic count as you've shown in your query.  To perform the aggregate with out having excess duplicates for a given day you need to eliminate columns that are providing non distinct values.  Mostly that's your alert start and end dates, and the `asset_id` and `geofence_id`.

The query below will give you the count of alters that occurred for the requested `group_id` and `reason_id`s that occurred for each of the last 30 days.

```
select cal.trunc_date
     , assets.group_id
     , alert.reason_id
     , count( alert.asset_id) TOTAL_ASSETS
  from g_alert_history alert
  join V_ACTIVE_ASSETS assets
    on assets.asset_id=alert.asset_id
  join v_app_calendar cal
    on alert.START_DATE_DEVICE < cal.trunc_date + 1
   and (alert.END_DATE_DEVICE is null or cal.trunc_date <= alert.END_DATE_DEVICE)
 where alert.REASON_ID in (1,2)
   and assets.group_id=1462
   and cal.trunc_date between trunc(sysdate - 30) and sysdate
 group by cal.trunc_date
     , assets.group_id
     , alert.reason_id
 order by cal.trunc_date
     , assets.group_id
     , alert.reason_id;
```